# How to traceroute in adb shell?

Tags: android, shell, adb, traceroute

I have a rooted device, I type "su" in adb shell, then I try to traceroute.
It says "traceroute: not found".
I can't find traceroute in any bin folders.

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traceroute is not avaiable with standard Android distribution. You may want to try installing BusyBox on your device: http://www.ihackintosh.com/2009/12/how-to-install-busybox-on-a-rooted-device/

It contains many useful tools that are avaiable on UNIX systems and are also working for Android. It can be downloaded here: http://www.busybox.net/

Answer (score 4):

After installing busybox run the following command:

```
$su
# /path to folder where u have installed busybox/busybox traceroute ip
```

like i have installed the busybox in `/system/xbin` folder then command is

```
# /system/xbin/busybox traceroute  74.125.236.66
```

Answer (score 1):

Understanding `traceroute` could be helpful:
It simply sends packets to your desired destination and increases the time-to-live (ttl) field. Every router (hop) will return a packet to the sender if the ttl is zero. With this mecanism you are able to trace the route of your packet through the network.

Knowing this, you could simply ping your destination an manually increase the ttl field. i.E (on adb shell, no root required):

```
ping -t 1 -c 1 8.8.8.8
ping -t 2 -c 1 8.8.8.8
ping -t 3 -c 1 8.8.8.8
...
ping -t 255 -c 1 8.8.8.8
```

the output could look like this:

```
From 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 Time to live exceeded
```

Now you can see the ips adresses of every hop in your way. You may stop increasing the ttl when you have reached the destination.

If you like you could wrap it into a skript (very basic sample):

```
for /l %x in (1, 1, 10) do adb shell ping -t %x -c 1 8.8.8.8>>ouput.log
```